# Strange behavior of Windows Start Command

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line

On Windows 7 x64 the following line run from a CMD window simply opens another CMD Window. It does not actually run myprog.exe.

```
  START "c:\program files\myprogram\myprog.exe"
```

Is there some special usage I need to know about START command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's telling `start` to create a new console with the title *c:\program files\myprogram\myprog.exe*

You need to `start "" "c:\program files\myprogram\myprog.exe"`

Comment: "start /?" isn't very clear, but tries to show that the first parameter, if it is in quotation marks, is the title that will be used for the window.

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me bananas. The help text seems to suggest that "title" is optional.