# Batch file is not working as expected

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

So I have this batch file

```
START "%userprofile%\Desktop\Rebuild\JayBotWatcher.exe"
CALL "%userprofile%\Desktop\Rebuild\InventoryExporter.exe" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Rebuild\JayBot.exe"
```

The second line works fine,  but the first fails for some reason and doesn't launch the .exe.

If I remove the quotes it works fine on PCs with no spaces in their username, but spaces in the username kill it on other pcs.

What am I missing?

Comment: Start take the first argument in double quotes as the window title, so insert a dummy pair `start "" "your command"`

Comment: Duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/550662/strange-behavior-of-windows-start-command or one from along that chain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange behavior of Windows Start Command](https://superuser.com/questions/550662/strange-behavior-of-windows-start-command)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use the "start" command with spaces in the path?](https://superuser.com/questions/239565/can-i-use-the-start-command-with-spaces-in-the-path)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid path problems with the START commandline I always use the /D parameter. Like this:

```
START /D "%userprofile%\Desktop\Rebuild" JayBotWatcher.exe
```

This way should work.